# How to query array of objects as part of term query

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am using elasticsearch 5.5.0.

Im my index i have data of type attraction part of the json in elastic looks like:

```
"directions": "Exit the M4 at Junction 1",
      "phoneNumber": "03333212001",
      "website": "https://www.londoneye.com/",
      "postCode": "SE1 7PB",
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": "ce4cf4d0-6ddd-49fd-a8fe-3cbf7be9b61d",
          "name": "Theater"
        },
        {
          "id": "5fa1a3ce-fd5f-450f-92b7-2be6e3d0df90",
          "name": "Family"
        },
        {
          "id": "ed492986-b8a7-43c3-be3d-b17c4055bfa0",
          "name": "Outdoors"
        }
      ],
      "genres": [],
      "featuredImage": "https://www.daysoutguide.co.uk/media/1234/london-eye.jpg",
      "images": [],
      "region": "London",
```

My next query looks like:

```
 var query2 = Query<Attraction>.Bool(
            bq => bq.Filter(
                fq => fq.Terms(t => t.Field(f => f.Region).Terms(request.Region.ToLower())),
                fq => fq.Terms(t => t.Field(f => f.Categories).Terms(request.Category.ToLower())))
```

The query generated looks like:

```
    {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "region": [
              "london"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "categories": [
              "family"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

That returns no results. If i take out the categories bit i get results.  So i am trying to do term filter on categories which is an array of objects.  Looks like I am doing this query wrong.  Anyone any hints on how to get this to work?

Regards

Ismail

Comment: I think you want to specify the full path of the field: `categories.name`. That should work.

Comment: You should use nested query, you will find usage in [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/5.x/nested-query-usage.html).

Comment: rob, not sure how you do that with Nest client? I know how to do with DSL

Comment: @Ismail Yes, this is the example for NEST client ;)

Comment: @rob so replace (f => f.Categories) with ("categories.name")  ??

Comment: May you share `Attraction` class?

Comment: @Rob that worked so my query part looks like                     fq => fq.Terms(t => t.Field("categories.name").Terms(request.Category.ToLower())))  many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still use strongly typed properties access by using:

`t.Field(f => f.Categories.First().Name)`

`NEST`'s property inferrer will reader will read over `.First()` and yield `categories.name`.

`t.Field(f => f.Categories[0].Name)` works as well.